# why does bot.get_updates() in python telegram bot API return deleted messages?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

So I'm trying to just forward messages in a particular chat_id to another one but I get error every once a while that the message to be forwarded doesnt exist :

updates = bot.get_updates()

bot.forward_message(dest_chat_id,src_chat_id, message_id = message_id)

*** telegram.error.BadRequest: Message to forward not found

which is because apparently the message has been deleted by the poster. So why is the deleted message still listed in the updates list at all and is there a way to find out if the message had been deleted before forwarding it ? sth like an attribute or a flag somewhere in the updates[i] object ?